# c++ Deseo leer datos de un archivo, pero estan guardados como vectores

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Verán lo que trato de hacer es una función que me permita leer lo que guarde en el archivo de texto "leads". Me base en un ejercicio en el cual no usamos struct para definir las variables, pero al momento de intentar llamar a la información que guarde, trato de llamar a la variable lead[i].nom, que representa el nombre del cliente, y así con los demás
datos.

```
struct cliente
{
    string nom,correo,fecha;
    char num[8];
    int interes, tipo, estado, presupuesto;
};
cliente *lead= new cliente [cantidad];
```

El caso es que no entiendo a que variable debería mandar a llamar para me muestre el nombre por ejemplo: guarde en la variable `lead[i].nom` el nombre Pepe, al mandarla a llamar deseo que me muestre en pantalla los datos de Pepe.
Intente haciendo esto:

```
void buscar(){
    string bnombre;
    ifstream mostrar;
    bool encontrado = false;
    mostrar.open("leads.txt",ios::in);
    
    if(mostrar.is_open()){
    cout<<"ingrese el nombre del cliente que desea buscar"<<endl;
    cin>>bnombre;
    mostrar>>lead[i].nom;
    while(!mostrar.eof()&& !encontrado){
    mostrar>>lead[i].num;
    mostrar>>lead[i].correo;
    mostrar>>lead[i].interes;
    mostrar>>lead[i].tipo;
    }
        cout<<"Nombre del cliente"<<lead[i].nom;
    }
    }
```

Para guardar dicha informacion use esta funcion:

```
// ingreso de datos//
    void ingreso(){ 
    ofstream data;
        int cantidad;
        cout<<"cuantos clientes desea ingresar?"<<endl;
        cin>>cantidad;
        cliente *lead= new cliente [cantidad];
        data.open("leads.txt",ios::app);
            if(data.fail())
                {
                    cout<<"no se pudo abrir el archivo";
                    exit(1);
                }
        
        for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++)
        {
        system("cls");
        int longcadena,longbase=8;

        cout<<"Ingrese el nombre de la persona"<<" "<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>lead[i].nom;
        do
        {
        cout<<"Ingrese correctamente su numero de telefono"<<" "<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>lead[i].num;
        longcadena=strlen(lead[i].num);
        }
        while(longcadena<longbase);
        cout<<"Ingrese su correo electronico"<<" "<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>lead[i].correo;
        
        cout<<"Ingrese el numero que corresponda a su interes"<<endl;
        cout<<"1. Compra de inmueble | 2. Venta de Inmueble"<<endl;     
        cin>>lead[i].interes;
        
        switch(lead[i].interes){
            case 1:{
                cout<<"Ingrese el tipo de inmueble que busca comprar"<<endl;
            cout<<"1. Casa | 2. Apartamento | 3. Local"<<endl;      
            cin>>lead[i].tipo;
            
                if(lead[i].tipo = 1)
                {
                cout<<"Ingrese su presupuesto mensual"<<endl;
                cin>>lead[i].presupuesto;
                } else
                if(lead[i].tipo=2){
                    cout<<"Ingrese su presupuesto mensual"<<endl;
                    cin>>lead[i].presupuesto;
                }else
                if(lead[i].tipo=3)
                {
                    cout<<"Ingrese su presupuesto mensual"<<endl;
                    cin>>lead[i].presupuesto;
                }
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                    cout<<"Ingrese el tipo de inmueble que busca rentar"<<endl;
            cout<<"1. Casa | 2. Apartamento | 3. Local"<<endl;      
            cin>>lead[i].tipo;
            
                if(lead[i].tipo=1)
                {
                cout<<"Ingrese su precio de renta mensual"<<endl;
                cin>>lead[i].presupuesto;
                } else
                if(lead[i].tipo=2){
                    cout<<"Ingrese su precio de renta mensual"<<endl;
                    cin>>lead[i].presupuesto;
                }else
                if(lead[i].tipo=3)
                {
                    cout<<"Ingrese su precio de renta mensual"<<endl;
                    cin>>lead[i].presupuesto;
                }
                break;
                default:{
                    cout<<"Opcion no valida, intente de nuevo"<<endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }       
                cout<<"Ingresa la fecha"<<endl;
                cin>>lead[i].fecha;
                
                cout<<"El Lead esta activo"<<endl;
                lead[i].estado = 1;             

    data<<lead[i].nom<<"\n"<<lead[i].num<<"\n"<<lead[i].correo<<"\n"<<lead[i].interes<<"\n"
        <<lead[i].tipo<<"\n"<<lead[i].presupuesto<<"\n";
    data.close();
}

}
```

Según comprendi, para traer del archivo de texto a la memoria usamos :

```
void buscarr(ifstream &Lec){
    system("cls");
    Lec.open("jugadores.txt",ios::in);
    string nombre,color,codigo,bcodigo;
    bool encontrado=  false;
    cout<<"Ingrese el codigo del jugador"<<endl;
    cin>>bcodigo;
    Lec>>nombre;// en donde lo que mandamos a llamar es a la variable en especifico.
    while(!Lec.eof()&& !encontrado){
        Lec>>color;
        Lec>>codigo;
        if(codigo == bcodigo){
            cout<<"Nombre-----------:"<<nombre<<endl;
            cout<<"Color de Equipo-----------:"<<color<<endl;
            cout<<"Codigo de jugador-----------:"<<codigo<<endl;
            cout<<endl;
            encontrado = true;
        } 
        Lec>>nombre;
    }
    Lec.close();
    if(!encontrado)
        cout<<"No se encontro el codigo ingresado"<<endl;
        system("pause");
     
}
```

Comment: Puedes clarificar un poco mas la pregunta, no termino de enteder cual es el problema?

Comment: intente ampliar un poco mi duda, deseo saber a que variable deberia mandar a llamar desde el archivo de texto en donde se guardo la informacion, si debo llamar a lead[i].nom o a la variable que corresponde dentro de la estructura que seria en este caso string nom;